# sed delete between two patterns deletes until end if second pattern is not found

Tags: sed

I'm using `sed` to remove tags in a configuration file, but I accidentally stumbled upon a problem, for which I'll use a basic example:

Contents of `numbers.txt` file:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

Delete between two numbers (including the numbers themselves):

```
sed '/4/,/6/d' numbers.txt
```

Yields (as expected):

```
0
1
2
3
7
8
9
```

But if I remove the `6` line from `numbers.txt`, I would expect the same command to yield *all* of `numbers.txt` since it cannot find the second pattern, but instead it simply deletes everything after the `4` line (presumably because the search for `6` reached the end of the file, so that's the value it returns):

```
0
1
2
3
```

My question is: how do I modify the `sed` statement to simply do nothing in such an event?

Comment: Why do you expect that? The behavior you see is not particularly unexpected.

Comment: It isn't after I looked into how sed's internal flow control work, and I can see how you would think that if you're familiar with it, but I interpret the syntax as "Find a range that begins with '4' and ends with '6', then delete the lines"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/4/{:a;$!{N;/6/Md;ba}}' file
```

Build your own loop and only delete the accumulated lines in the pattern space if the end condition is met.

N.B. The `M` flag on the end condition to allow matches on multiple lines gathered up in the pattern space.

The `/start/,/end/d` is a control structure that upon finding `start` immediately deletes lines until `end` or the end of the file. Therefore there are two *end* conditions, the address `/end/` or `$`. As the action (in this case deletion) is immediate, it can not be reversed if the `/end/` condition is not met, for this reason the lines to be deleted need to gathered up and deleted or not depending on one of two conditions, either `/end/`( delete) or `$` (do not delete).

- `/4/{...}` start address of actions within the curly braces.
- `:a` the address of the start of a loop named `a`
- `$!{...}` if not the end of file actions within the curly braces.
- `N` append a newline and then the next line to the pattern space.
- `/6/Md` end address and delete command if found i.e. this will delete all lines in the pattern space that have been appended by the `N` command.
- `ba` goto command, breaks to the loop address `a`. This enables the loop mechanism to continue until one of two conditions `/6/` or`$`.

N.B. If the end of file condition is met, the `/4/{...}` ends and the accumulated lines are printed as normal.

Comment: Works, but I don't know why.  Could you elaborate on the syntax, please?

Comment: Excellent, thanks. I tried finding information on the {...;...;...} syntax in sed (which I assume is specific to GNU sed) but was having difficulty. Do you know a good resource for that? Also, I read that this type of look-ahead multi-line processing is inappropriate for a stream tool like sed. Is there a basic tool that's more appropriate?

Comment: @robbie9485 click on the [sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sed) tag and look for the link [learn more](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sed/info).

Comment: The [Grymoire's Sed Tutorial](http://grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html) is pretty good deep-dive on `sed`. Good luck.

Comment: How can I only delete a specific match within the appended lines? `/6/Md` is deleting everything that has been appended by `N`, but I only want to delete empty lines. I would have thought `/6/M{ /^$/d; }` would do the trick, but it isn't. and `/6/{/^$/Md}` deletes everything. https://www.grymoire.com/Unix/SedChart.pdf I don't see `M` at all in the grymoire sed chart and having difficulty finding more about it

Comment: @nathanrogers since each line is appended the last line can be identified by `\n[^\n]*$` and thus if such a line were empty then it would match `\n$` or `\n\s*$`. So the substitution command `s/\n$//` might be inserted after the line is appended and before it is matched `/6/M`. However to delete empty lines between a range use `/start/,/end/{/^$/d}`